# How I remove the deleted record in OAI?

Tags: oai, ojs, oai-pmh

Please How I remove deleted records in OAI?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

OJS uses “tombstones” to refer to deleted records. If you want to remove these, you can do so from the data_object_tombstones, data_object_tombstone_settings, and data_object_tombstone_oai_set_objects tables.

Comment: OJS uses “tombstones” to refer to deleted records. If you want to remove these, you can do so from the data_object_tombstones, data_object_tombstone_settings, and data_object_tombstone_oai_set_objects tables. but where I find those setting can you help me or you have any tutorial video link then please send me. Thanks